# I am making a class to draw a rectangle in random locations using a class to do it, I get the error cannot find symbol

Tags: java, draw

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, int canvasHeight)
{
  drawRectangle(10,10,10,10);
}
```

I know I can not add

```
public void drawRectangle
```

and now I am completely stuck, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`error cannot find symbol` means there is no method named `drawRectangle`, so you should create one.

You may add:

```
public void drawRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
  //your implementation of drawing rectangle here 
}
```